# Is this the correct way to make a pointer that points on an array of lists (structs)?

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

We have this struct:

```
typedef struct picture* picPtr
typedef struct picture{
 int id;
 int likes;
 picPtr next;
}Picture;
```

And we have this function:

```
void add_picture(picPtr arr[], int id)
```

what i want to do in this function is make a temporary pointer to that array in a certain place(notice that this array is type picPtr making it an array of linked list meaning that each cell of that array has a linked list. so what i did is this:

```
picPtr* temp = (arr +id);
```

is this the correct way?

I wrote what I tried but I got points deducted in my exams, idk if its because of this.

Comment: Yes, it is a correct way.:) The parameter declaration picPtr arr[] actually looks like picPtr *arr

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do yourself an *enormous* lifetime favor and avoid hiding pointer types in typedef aliases. There are only two good reasons to do it, and this is *neither* of those.  It may seem clever, but it rapidly becomes a logistical nightmare. C programmers love splats (™). They're the calling card of pointers, and the logic that surrounds them (which is the majority of most C programs). Don't inhibit that; learn the language well enough to be explicit with splats, and embrace them.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll bite. What are those two good reasons?

Comment: `picPtr *temp = &arr[id];` is perhaps more readable.  Lots of people put the * next to the type but it's doesn't work you expect for multiple variables (even if you should avoid multiple variable definitions on a given line).

Comment: @AllanWind 1. Black-box "Handle" APIs (where the pointer itself is opaque to the user that it is, in fact, a pointer), 2. Callback function pointer  for type hardening callbacks specified as function arguments. Outside of those, I've yet to discover a legitimate case where pointer-type alias obfuscation is *ever* sensible.

Comment: @WhozCraig I hate hiding function pointers too. It is better to typede function type `typedef int foo(int);` and the `foo *fncPtr` or `void bar(func *funcPtr)`

Answer (score 1):

Within a function declared this way ...

> ```
> void add_picture(picPtr arr[], int id)
> ```

... identifier `arr` has type `picPtr *`, also known as `struct picture **`.

In such a context, this declaration ...

> ```
> picPtr* temp = (arr +id);
> ```

... is syntactically valid, does not violate any language constraints, and is equivalent to:

```
picPtr *temp = &arr[id];
```

Whether that makes it *correct* is a separate question that we do not have sufficient information to answer.  It may be perfectly valid, yet not suited for the intended purpose, for example.  Or there might be other reasons for it to be unacceptable, such as issues with the value of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a good way.

1. `typedef struct picture* picPtr;`Horrible habit of hiding the pointers behind the typedefs. Never do this (even for function pointers - better declare funtuon type and then use the usual pointer syntax).

- . If you want to pass the pointer referencing the first element of the array:
  `void add_picture(Picture *arr, int id)`
- if you want to pass the pointer to pointer to `Picture` : `void add_picture(Picture **arr, int id)` (and not that it is not a pointer to the array).
- Passing pointer to the array: void `add_picture(size_t sizeOfArray, Picture (*arr)[sizeOfArray], int id)`

3. `picPtr* temp = (arr +id);` I do not think that you want a pointer to pointer to `Picture` in this statement and as you hide the pointer behind the typedef, you have lost the track of what is referencing what.

- If passed a pointer to `Picture`: `Picute *temp = arr[id]` or `Picute *temp = arr + id`
- If passed a pointer to pointer to `Picture`:`Picute *temp = (*arr)[id]` or `Picute *temp = (*arr) + id`
- If passed a pointer to array of `Picture` elements:`Picute *temp = &arr[id]`